# Rails ActiveRecord subclass losing primary key after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have want to create and then update my subclass, but after creating it, it loses its primary_key, making any update impossible.

My (simplified) setup is the following:

`Rails 4.2.9`
`ruby-2.1.10`

Models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible   :firstname,
                    :lastname
end

class SimpleContact < Contact
  self.primary_key  = 'id'
end
```

Both models sharing the `contacts` table (STI).

Controller:

```
module Public
  class FilmEntriesController < PublicController

  # ...

  def create
    logger.debug "SIM PK #{SimpleContact.primary_key}" # id

    contact = SimpleContact.create()

    logger.debug "SIM PK after create #{SimpleContact.primary_key}" # nil

    contact.update_attributes({"firstname"=>"Moe", "lastname"=>"Test"})
  end

end
```

The contacts table was created with this migration:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string  :firstname    # | kontakt_vorname    | varchar(64)
      t.string  :lastname     # | kontakt_nachname   | varchar(64)
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The full error msg is then

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Public::FilmEntriesController#create
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'contacts.' in 'where clause': UPDATE 
`contacts` SET `firstname` = 'Moe', `lastname` = 'Test', `updated_at` 
= '2017-09-07 11:09:39' WHERE `contacts`.`` = 21964
```

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: Please show a database migration for `contacts`.

Comment: Why do you set `primary_key` to `"id"` – isn't that the default value?

Comment: @mudasobwa: i added the migration to the question

Comment: @Stefan primary_key was set explicitly because i got an error mentioning that ActiveRecord could find a primary key for contacts when modifying SimpleContact .

Comment: @PiezoPea do you mean _"could **not** find a primary key"_? Anyway, please show that error. Maybe the problem is caused by something else.

Comment: @Stefan if i add `contact = SimpleContact.find(contact.primary_key_value)` after the `SimpleContact.create`-line, i'm getting `ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey in Public::FilmEntriesController#create
Unknown primary key for table contacts in model SimpleContact.` but this is an subsequent fault i think.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea where that error comes from. Setting `primary_key` may be a workaround, but it can't be the solution (and could cause many other problems later on). You should try to find the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

To use STI you need a `type` column in the respective table in the database. Just add to your migration:

```
t.string   "type", default: "Contact", null: false
```

and remove

```
self.primary_key  = 'id'
```

from your model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, maybe i got STI wrong, but i don't need the type specification. It's enough if SimpleContact is writing to Contact. Do you think this could be a problem for Rails/AR?

Comment: “i don't need the type specification”—you don’t, but Rails **do**, they have to know what class to instantiate.

Comment: "you don’t, but Rails do" -- <3

Comment: From rails api about STI: "Active Record allows inheritance by storing the name of the class in a column that by default is named “type” (can be changed by overwritingBase.inheritance_column).".

Comment: OK :-) 
.. But it does not change the error, i'm still getting: ` ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Public::FilmEntriesController#create
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'contacts.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `contacts` SET `firstname` = 'Moe', `lastname` = 'Test', `updated_at` = '2017-09-08 06:14:28' WHERE `contacts`.`` = 21969`

Comment: That is because `create` does not persist an object in the database. Use `create!` instead.

Comment: @mudasobwa no, create persists: `  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO `contacts` (`type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('SimpleContact', '2017-09-11 09:04:17', '2017-09-11 09:04:17')`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are having problems because you set the SimpleContact model to NOT generate a ID by itself. I'm deducting that because you are using this line of code in SimpleContact:

```
self.primary_key  = 'id'
```

and because none id is being generate.

You can check whether you set or not in you migration file for the SimpleContact table.

If that is true, one way to solve it could be use this line of code in your SimpleContact model:

```
before_create { self.id = generator_id() }
```

Where the generator_id method could be any value of id you want. That way your current code would work.

Another way to solve it would be set the SimpleContact table to generate the id by itself. You can google it to see how it is done.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
SimpleContact is using the `contacts` table (clarified my Question!) and in the table there is an `id` field which should be used.
The problem is, that after creating, no id is set on the object which was created.